# HtmlUnit gets page error

Tags: java, parsing, htmlunit

I am trying to parse this page.

```
http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/07/08/us-china-cybersecurity-idUSKCN0PI09020150708
```

My code looks like this

```
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
  final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/07/08/us-alibaba-singapore-post-idUSKCN0PI03J20150708");
  System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

It gives me a lot of warnings and a huge call stack. Mostly related to javascript engine.
I have used these options

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000000);
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(1000000);
```

But nothing seems to work. This page executes javascript to load the content of the page. I need to wait for the page to load to get the content. Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `wait` just after getting the page, also there is an error of `"addImpression" is not defined`, I don't know in which JavaScript it is defined.

I feel like you are not using recent version, since there are not lot of warnings.

With [latest snapshot](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts) I get the content by using:

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/07/08/us-alibaba-singapore-post-idUSKCN0PI03J20150708");
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    System.out.println(page.asText());
}
```